# Regex to find words with letters and numbers separated or not by symbols

Tags: java, regex

I need to build a regex that match words with these patterns:

Letters and numbers:

> A35, 35A, B503X, 1ABC5

Letters and numbers separated by "-", "/", "\":

> AB-10, 10-AB, A10-BA, BA-A10, etc...

I wrote this regex for it:

```
\b[A-Za-z]+(?=[(?<!\-|\\|\/)\d]+)[(?<!\-|\\|\/)\w]+\b|\b[0-9]+(?=[(?<!\-|\\|\/)A-Za-z]+)[(?<!\-|\\|\/)\w]+\b
```

It works partially, but it's match only letters or only numbers separated by symbols.
Example:

> 10-10, open-office, etc.

And I don't wanna this matches.

I guess that my regex is very repetitive and somewhat ugly. 
But it's what I have for now.

Could anyone help me?

I'm using java/groovy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the future you can play around with this tool, it is a lifesaver for me:  http://regexpal.com/

Comment: What's the difference between what you do and don't want to match? Each set must contain letters and numbers?

Comment: In this string: "10 10-10 open-office 10B A10 UCS5000 code DV-3000 300-BR", the regex need match this words: "10B, A10, UCS5000, DV-3000, 300-BR". Letters AND numbers in the same word, separated OR NOT by symbols -, /, \

Comment: What about leading and/or trailing symbols, like in `-x4, 4x-, 4-x-, -4-x or -4-x-`?

Comment: @fethz Please, answer to question of _user _unknown_, we do need to have this answer to craft correct solution.

Comment: @fethz Also, what are the authorized characters to separate the words you look after ? For exemple, in **'UY %AB-12 hp'** , is **'AB-12'** a valid word ?

Comment: @fethz Also bis, are words like **'ghj-10-ty23-re/78'** and **'ZE-/-L47'** valid ?

Comment: @eyquem In my case, the words are separated by spaces. I use \b to do this. And the words 'ghj-10-ty23-re/78' and 'ZE-/-L47' are valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting challenge. Here is a java program with a regex that picks out the types of "words" you are after:

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "A35, 35A, B503X, 1ABC5 " +
            "AB-10, 10-AB, A10-BA, BA-A10, etc... " +
            "10-10, open-office, etc.";
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
            "# Match special word having one letter and one digit (min).\n" +
            "\\b                       # Match first word having\n" +
            "(?=[-/\\\\A-Za-z]*[0-9])  # at least one number and\n" +
            "(?=[-/\\\\0-9]*[A-Za-z])  # at least one letter.\n" +
            "[A-Za-z0-9]+              # Match first part of word.\n" +
            "(?:                       # Optional extra word parts\n" +
            "  [-/\\\\]                # separated by -, / or //\n" +
            "  [A-Za-z0-9]+            # Match extra word part.\n" +
            ")*                        # Zero or more extra word parts.\n" +
            "\\b                       # Start and end on a word boundary", 
            Pattern.COMMENTS);
        Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(s);
        while (regexMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.print(regexMatcher.group() + ", ");
        } 
    }
}
```

Here is the correct output:

`A35, 35A, B503X, 1ABC5, AB-10, 10-AB, A10-BA, BA-A10,`

Note that the only complex regexes which are "ugly", are those that are not properly formatted and commented!

Comment: Excellent! It's exactly what I need! Thank you ridgerunner!

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
([a-zA-Z]+[-\/\\]?[0-9]+|[0-9]+[-\/\\]?[a-zA-Z]+)
```

In Java `\\` and `\/` should be escaped:

```
([a-zA-Z]+[-\\\/\\\\]?[0-9]+|[0-9]+[-\\\/\\\\]?[a-zA-Z]+)
```

Comment: This regex will match words with only letters or only numbers too.

Comment: This almost worked. If I have this case: DV5-500, this regex matches only DV5. I'll edit my question to be more clear about the possibilities.

Comment: You don't need to mask a slash.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me to write my solution in Python, I don't know enough Java to write in Java.

```
pat = re.compile('(?=(?:([A-Z])|[0-9])' ## This part verifies that
                 '[^ ]*'                ## there are at least one
                 '(?(1)\d|[A-Z]))'      ## letter and one digit.
                 '('   
                 '(?:(?<=[ ,])[A-Z0-9]|\A[A-Z0-9])'  # start of second group
                 '[A-Z0-9-/\\\\]*'
                 '[A-Z0-9](?= |\Z|,)'               # end of second group
                 ')',  
                 re.IGNORECASE) # this group 2 catches the string
```

.

My solution catches the desired string in the second group: `((?:(?<={ ,])[A-Z0-9]|\A[A-Z0-9])[A-Z0-9-/\\\\]*[A-Z0-9](?= |\Z|,))`

.

The part before it verifies that one letter at least and one digit at least are present in the catched string:

`(?(1)\d|[A-Z])` is a conditional regex that means "if group(1) catched something, then there must be a digit here, otherwise there must be a letter"

The group(1) is `([A-Z])`  in `(?=(?:([A-Z])|[0-9])`

`(?:([A-Z])|[0-9])`  is a non-capturing group that matches a letter (catched) OR a digit, so when it matches a letter, the group(1)  isn't empty

.

The flag re.IGNORECASE allows to treat strings with upper or lower cased letters.

.

In the second group, I am obliged to write `(?:(?<=[ ,])[A-Z0-9]|\A[A-Z0-9])` because lookbehind assertions with non fixed length are not allowed. This part signifies one character that can't be **'-'** preceded by a blank or the head of the string.

At the opposite, `(?= |\Z[,)` means 'end of string or a comma or a blank after'

.

**This regex supposes that the characters `'-'` , `'/'` , `'\'` can't be the first character or the last one of a captured string** . Is it right ?

```
import re

pat = re.compile('(?=(?:([A-Z])|[0-9])' ## (from here)  This part verifies that
                 '[^ ]*'                 #              there are at least one
                 '(?(1)\d|[A-Z]))'      ## (to here)    letter and one digit.
                 '((?:(?<=[ ,])[A-Z0-9]|\A[A-Z0-9])'
                 '[A-Z0-9-/\\\\]*'
                 '[A-Z0-9](?= |\Z|,))',
                 re.IGNORECASE) # this group 2 catches the string

ch = "ALPHA13 10 ZZ 10-10 U-R open-office ,10B a10 UCS5000 -TR54 code vg4- DV-3000 SEA 300-BR  gt4/ui bn\\3K"

print [ mat.group(2) for mat in pat.finditer(ch) ]

s = "A35, 35A, B503X,1ABC5 " +\
     "AB-10, 10-AB, A10-BA, BA-A10, etc... " +\
     "10-10, open-office, etc."

print [ mat.group(2) for mat in pat.finditer(s) ]
```

result

```
['ALPHA13', '10B', 'a10', 'UCS5000', 'DV-3000', '300-BR', 'gt4/ui', 'bn\\3K']
['A35', '35A', 'B503X', '1ABC5', 'AB-10', '10-AB', 'A10-BA', 'BA-A10']
```

Answer (score 0):

My first pass yields

```
(^|\s)(?!\d+[-/\\]?\d+(\s|$))(?![A-Z]+[-/\\]?[A-Z]+(\s|$))([A-Z0-9]+[-/\\]?[A-Z0-9]+)(\s|$)
```

Sorry, but it's not java formatted (you'll need to edit the \ \s etc.). Also, you can't use `\b` b/c a word boundary is anything that is not alphanumeric and underscore, so I used `\s` and the start and end of the string.

This is still a bit raw

**EDIT**

Version 2, slightly better, but could be improved for performance by usin possessive quantifiers. It matches `ABC76` `AB-32` `3434-F` etc, but not `ABC` or `19\23` etc.

```
((?<=^)|(?<=\s))(?!\d+[-/\\]?\d+(\s|$))(?![A-Z]+[-/\\]?[A-Z]+(\s|$))([A-Z0-9]+[-/\\]?[A-Z0-9]+)((?=$)|(?=\s))
```

Answer (score 0):

A condition (A OR NOT A) can be omited. So symbols can savely been ignored.

```
for (String word : "10 10-10 open-office 10B A10 UCS5000 code DV-3000 300-BR".split (" "))
    if (word.matches ("(.*[A-Za-z].*[0-9])|(.*[0-9].*[A-Za-z].*)"))
         // do something
```

You didn't mention -x4, 4x-, 4-x-, -4-x or -4-x-, I expect them all to match.

My expression looks just for something-alpha-something-digits-something, where something might be alpha, digits or symbols, and the opposite: something-alpha-something-digits-something. If something else might occur, like !#$~()[]{} and so on, it would get longer.

Tested with scala:

```
scala> for (word <- "10 10-10 open-office 10B A10 UCS5000 code DV-3000 300-BR".split (" ")
     | if word.matches ("(.*[A-Za-z].*[0-9])|(.*[0-9].*[A-Za-z].*)")) yield word          
res89: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(10B, A10, UCS5000, DV-3000, 300-BR)
```

Slightly modified to filter matches:

```
String s = "A35, 35A, B53X, 1AC5, AB-10, 10-AB, A10-BA, BA-A10, etc. -4x, 4x- -4-x- 10-10, oe-oe, etc";
Pattern pattern  = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile ("\\b([^ ,]*[A-Za-z][^ ,]*[0-9])[^ ,]*|([^ ,]*[0-9][^ ,]*[A-Za-z][^ ,]*)\\b");
matcher = pattern.matcher (s);
while (matcher.find ()) { System.out.print (matcher.group () + "|") }
```

But I still have an error, which I don't find:

```
A35|35A|B53X|1AC5|AB-10|10-AB|A10-BA|BA-A10|-4x|4x|-4-x|
```

4x should be 4x-, and -4-x should be -4-x-.

Comment: It's an interesting solution, but i can't split the original string by spaces (it's a rule of the solution that i'm developing). Thanks!

Comment: The splitting is just to test the example. You asked for `matching words`, not `extracting matching words`.